# Fundamental idea of this memory denial of service simulation using array copy?

Tags: computer-architecture, memory-access

I am just watching this lecture [Computer Organization - Introduction And Basics](https://youtu.be/BJ87rZCGWU0?list=PLEMlgDT2xAMDPKMNlE0LM-hGdt6ABX28W&t=2598) where
the lecturer mentions about using a simple code to demonstrate how memory denial of service can be simulated in DRAM by exploiting an optimzation DRAM Controller does internally. The optimization seems to be that DRAM Controller serves the same **row buffer** whenever possible for the instructions coming to the pipeline and so it can be exploited by sending instructions that use a very localized data giving it priority.

```
//initialize large arrays A and B

for(j=0; j<n; j++)
{
index = j*linesize;
A[index] = B[index]
}
```

I just wanted to understand the fundamental concept of this approach. The Lecturer says that the above code would copy an Array from `B` to `A`. However I am not sure how it actually would copy an Array from `B` to `A` because it doesn't seem to go over each index item.

My real doubt, assuming that this is just a simulation code which copies some part of `B` to `A` for demonstration purpose and that `linesize` is just a large value to make a `cache miss`, is if the central idea behind this something like:

a) chose an `index` that is **sufficiently** wide apart so that a       `cache miss` happens

b) **yet** the memory is **close** enough for it to be in the same `row` for the memory controller to serve from the same `row buffer`

Which is needed to simulate this DoS (denial of service) scenario?

Quoting from the paper that explains this in depth [Memory Performance Attacks - Denial Of Service In Multi Core Systems](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/memory-performance-attacks-denial-of-memory-service-in-multi-core-systems/)

> The arrays in stream are sized such that they are much larger than the
>   L2 cache on a core. Each array consists of 2.5M 128-byte elements. Stream (Figure 3(a)) has very high row-buffer locality since
>   consecutive cache misses almost always access the same row (limited
>   only by the size of the row-buffer).

Answer (score 2):

The idea is that this code does *not* copy the complete array, but due to the design of the memory hardware it takes just as much time as if it would. Reading and writing a single byte will move a whole cache line. So the code reading and writing does very little work, but causes the memory subsystem to perform a whole lot of work.

Comment: Thanks. That explains the first part of my question about full or partial copy and making the memory subsystem to perform a lot of work, but I was also interested to know the concept behind this simulation. My understanding is that it tries to access a memory that is distant enough to cause a cache line(?) miss, yet since in the same memory row (its an array after all hence it would be contigous memory location) so that we could simulate this scenario of `row-buffer` bias? Am I in the right direction, missing the point or not making any sense? Its advanced for an introduction hence aksed.

Comment: @Nishant Yes, the idea is to minimize processor work for the maximum number of cache lines accessed within an aligned region corresponding to the row-buffer. (The actual nature is a little more complicated. The row-buffer size across DRAM chips in a single "rank" is typically larger than 4KiB, so with 4KiB pages address translation might not map a buffer-sized region onto consecutive pages. In addition, DRAM has multiple banks; a more effective DoS would seek to keep them busy to discourage the memory controller from servicing accesses to them.)